# Allow anonymous access to a particular aspx file not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm dealing with an issue for the last 3 hours.
I have to build a project with WebForms. I'm setting the authentication like this:

```
 <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Backend/Default.aspx"></forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>

  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
</system.web>

<location path="Backend/Default.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Not only when executing the application, does not allow me to enter to Backend/Default.aspx (redirect the site to Account/Login.aspx, but neither allow to access to the login page. I'm getting a not authorized error.

Can anyone tell what I am missing?

Edit:
I have 2 files:

- Backend/Default.aspx
- Account/Login.aspx I want to be allowed to enter Default.aspx without authentication. But not only doesn't allow me, don't allow me Account/Login.aspx neither.

If I change

```
<location path="Account/Login.aspx">
```

To

```
<location path="Account">
```

It works. But I only need one file on this folder to be allowed and not the entire folder.

Please tell me if I can give more useful information

Comment: Your question is not complete. Please review [MCVE]. You would need to show the relevant login code.

Comment: I don't have login code. I can't even get login page working, that's my issue. What more information can I post?
I have 2 files:
- Backend/Default.aspx
- Account/Login.aspx
I want to be allowed to enter Default.aspx without authentication.
But not only doesn't allow me, don't allow me Account/Login.aspx neither.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing so I'm not sure if this will work, but it might give the right approach.

You have

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>    <-- this allows everyone everywhere, overriding the previous line.
</authorization>
```

Remove the `allow` line, blocking everyone from everything

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Then allow a specific folder

```
<location path="Backend/Default.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

---

Or, you can have 2 web.config files.

Start with this in the root of your site

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Then add *another* web.config file in the Account/ directory that has

```
<!--Block everyone from everything in this directory-->
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>

<!--But allow a specific file-->
<location path="Account/Login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Hth.